# How to disable beforeunload events (e.g. "Are you sure you want to leave this page?") in web browsers?

Tags: browser

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

> The beforeunload event is fired when the window, the document and its
>   resources are about to be unloaded.
>
> When a string is assigned to the returnValue Event property, a dialog
>   box appears, asking the users for confirmation to leave the page.
>   silently.

---

[image]

---

This popup window sometimes appears when I try to exit a website. The method is commonly abused by scam and spyware sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox you can completely disable beforeunload events by setting `dom.disable_beforeunload` to `true` in `about:config`. Extensions may be needed for other browsers.